# Android sending data phone to phone

Tags: android, networking, ip-address

Can you find the IP address of a freinds phone using their phone number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  A phone number has nothing to do with an IP address and that would require support from the carrier.  What you could do is send the person a text message that a custom application looks for.  The application could then respond with the phone's IP address.  That would be the only way to translate phone number to IP address.

Comment: I was afraid of that. That would be a serious battery killer to run a background service like that. I was investigating ways to implement pure peer to peer on the phone. It seems outside of hacking sms or email you would have to have some sort of server to handle initial connections.

Comment: Unfortunately.  Although having a "broadcast receiver" isn't terrible to the battery as it gets run only when a message is received, not all the time.  Check out the code here: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/